# Расчёт переменной

Tags: java

Начал изучать java, пробую первое задание и не знаю, куда копать.
Есть программа по выписке штрафов за превышение скорости. Надо изменить ее так, чтобы она учитывала, *где* произошло превышение - в городе или деревне.  По заданию нужно добавить переменную

```
boolean isTown = true;
```

и переменную с максимально разрешенной скоростью за городом

```
int countrySpeed = 90;
```

Теперь надо изменить способ расчёта переменной ​`overSpeed` ​таким образом, чтобы значение этой переменной зависело от значения переменной `​isTown`​. Я не знаю, как сделать. Код выглядит сейчас вот так

```
System.out.println("Система расчёта штрафов");

int carSpeed = 92;
boolean isTown = true;

int fineFor20to40 = 500;
int fineFor40to60 = 1000;
int fineFor60to80 = 2000;
int fineFor80andMore = 5000;

int townSpeed = 60;
int countrySpeed = 90;

if(isTown = "true") {
    int overSpeed = carSpeed - townSpeed;
}


if(overSpeed < 20) {
    System.out.println("Скорость не превышена или превышена незначительно");
}
else if(overSpeed >= 20 && overSpeed < 40) {
    System.out.println("Штраф: " + fineFor20to40);
}
else if(overSpeed >= 40 && overSpeed < 60) {
    System.out.println("Штраф: " + fineFor40to60);
}
else if(overSpeed >= 60 && overSpeed < 80) {
    System.out.println("Штраф: " + fineFor60to80);
}
else if(overSpeed >= 80) {
    System.out.println("Штраф: " + fineFor80andMore);
}
```

Буду очень благодарен за подсказку.
Спасибо.

Comment: ``if(isTown = "true")`` - нормальная IDE в этом месте будет кричать красным цветом. И этот код даже не будет работать. Здесь две синтаксические ошибки и одна стилистическая.

Comment: @Эникейщик я уже понял, снизу помогли исправить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int overSpeed;
if (isTown) { // в городе
    overSpeed = carSpeed - townSpeed;
} else {
    overSpeed = carSpeed - countrySpeed;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Все получилось.